# Why GitLab has option to disable sign in?

Tags: gitlab

I can't understand why GitLab has an option to disable the user to login on the site, can anyone give me an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

If a user leaves our company we disable the account and delete the ssh key.

It is not unusual that you do not delete the user account if a user leaves the company, but you always disable the accounts.